# Can I use idemix in ibm blockchain platform vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I'm a beginner in hyperledger fabric.I want to use ibm blockchain platform vscode extension for my project. I need to use idemix in my project alongside smart contracts. Can I use idemix in ibm blockchain platform vscode extension?

Answer (score 0):

The extension has no support for idemix and I don't know if microfab networks that the extension supports would be enabled for idemix either. You might still use the extension to manage your own network (see https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/wiki/Common-tasks-and-how-to-complete-them#connecting-to-another-instance-of-hyperledger-fabric) that has idemix enabled to deploy chaincode for example but the inbuilt transaction driver still relies on wallets using x509 certs so you would have to develop your own client to drive the chaincode.

This is speculative however as I've not tried this myself.

Comment: Thank you. I'll investigate more and check if someone try this or not.